# Symfony Dom Crawler Missing Node, Inconsistent Behaviour

Tags: php, symfony, css-selectors, components, domcrawler

With this code:

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');

$html = <<<'HTML'
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <p class="message">Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello Crawler!</p>
        <p>OUTSIDE
            <span>
                Child SPAN
            </span>
            <div>
                Child DIV
            </div>
            <p>
                Child PARAGRAPH
            </p>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>

HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$crawlerFiltered = $crawler->filter('body > p');

$results = [];
$childResults = [];
for ($i=0; $i<count($crawlerFiltered); $i++) {
    $results[] = $crawlerFiltered->eq($i)->html();

    $children = $crawlerFiltered->eq($i)->children();
    if (count($children)) {
        for ($j=0; $j<count($children); $j++) {
            $childResults[] = $children->eq($j)->html();
        }
    }
}

echo 'Parent Nodes:' . PHP_EOL;
var_export($results);
echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'Child Nodes:' . PHP_EOL;
var_export($childResults);
```

I get result:

```
Parent Nodes:
array (
  0 => 'Hello World!',
  1 => 'Hello Crawler!',
  2 => 'OUTSIDE
            <span>
                Child SPAN
            </span>
            ',
  3 => '
                Child PARAGRAPH
            ',
)
Child Nodes:
array (
  0 => '
                Child SPAN
            ',
)
```

That represents following problems:

1. Child result: no DIV or P (only inline tags)
2. Parent result: PHARAGRAPH is without tag, inconsistent with SPAN
3. Parent result: should contain only first `p` because second `p` (PHARAGRAPH) does not
   have `body` as parent but `p`

do you know why is that and how to fix problems as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation for this component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) states:

> Note
>
> The DomCrawler will attempt to automatically fix your HTML to match the official specification. For example, if you nest a `<p>` tag inside another `<p>` tag, it will be moved to be a sibling of the parent tag. This is expected and is part of the HTML5 spec.

You may have better luck using the built-in [DomDocument](http://php.net/DomDocument) classes. Most HTML parsers are designed to deal with ["tag soup"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup) and will try to correct perceived problems.

Comment: Indeed, despite what the title of this question suggests, this is actually for *consistency* with browsers, and it would be "inconsistent" if it didn't match browser behavior.